# Reference for subset of a matrices rows spans the row space of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

The row space of a matrix $A$ is the span $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \rangle$ of the $n$ rows of $A$. Does anyone know a reference, or quick proof, for the claim that there exist a subset of these vectors, $(a_{r_1}, \dots, a_{r_k})$, where $k = \operatorname{rank}(A)$, that spans the row space of $A$?

I am able to prove this by explicitly generating such a subset using row reduction. I.e., the rows containing pivots (and undoing any row transpositions) after $A$ is put into row echelon form gives one subset of these vectors. However, this seems like it should be an easily accessible 'fact'.

Comment: I think your argument is the best way of establishing that 'fact'.

Comment: I’m not convinced that your proposed method is guaranteed to find a basis for the row space, but it you row-reduce the _transpose_ of the matrix, the pivot columns will correspond to a linearly-independent subset in the usual way.

Comment: @amd what is this usual way you are referring to?

Comment: The columns of the original (pre-reduction) matrix that correspond to pivot columns in the reduced matrix are linearly independent, and in fact form a basis for the column space. If you haven’t learned this yet in your studies, you will soon.

Comment: @amd How does this give me a subset of the rows of the original matrix that spans the row space?

Comment: The columns of the transpose are the rows of the original matrix, therefore...

Comment: is it easy to see why "The columns of the original (pre-reduction) matrix that correspond to pivot columns in the reduced matrix are linearly independent, and in fact form a basis for the column space."?

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit, you’re method should work, too, but working with the transpose is easier—there’s not need to track row swaps.

Comment: You don't have to track row swaps if you do your best to get to row echelon form via addition only elementary row operations, but then it is tedious to write down the algorithm. Perhaps it is best if I just wrote it out to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: Multiplying a set of vectors by an invertible matrix preserves their independence. It remains to be shown that you get $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ vectors this way.

Comment: Basically, your claim is that "A subset of rows of $A$ that span the row space is given by $(a_{r_1}, \dots, a_{r_k})$, where $r_i$ are the column numbers containing pivots in the row echelon form of $A'$".

Comment: The proof of this claim does not seem obvious to me either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a quick proof using induction on the rank of a matrix. The claim is clearly true when the rank is 1. We will now show that the claim is true for matrices $A$ with rank $k+1$, assuming that the claim holds for matrices of rank $k$. Let $S = \{a_{r_1}, a_{r_2}, \dots, a_{r_l}\}$ denote the subset of rows of $A$ with minimal cardinality that spans the row space of $A$, and suppose for a contradiction that $l > k + 1$. Since this set has minimal cardinality, it must be possible to remove a row $a_{s_{k+1}}$ such that $S \setminus \{a_{s_{k+1}}\}$ has rank $k$. By the induction hypothesis there exist a subset of $S \setminus \{a_{s_{k+1}}\}$, comprising of the rows $\{a_{s_1}, a_{s_2}, \dots, a_{s_k}\}$, of cardinality $k$, that has rank $k$. But $\{a_{s_1}, a_{s_2}, \dots, a_{s_{k+1}}\}$ has rank $k + 1$, a contradiction to the minimality of the cardinality of $S$.